# Google Maps API: How to Set Scroll Zoom to Anchor in on One Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project, where I need the scroll zoom to zoom in on a marker (or alternatively on a specific point), and not on my cursor as is the default. Currently the scroll zoom zooms in on the cursor. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Set the center of you map"

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(  ,  )
```

Then add function to move to marker position

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function()
{

   map.panTo(marker.getPosition();

});
```